# Rails + Webpacker + React.js / Cannot find module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, webpacker

I'm learning React.js with Rails 4.2 (to prepare to work on it) but I have a lot of errors in my console.

So I'm using React 16.8 (with react-rails gem) + Rails 4.2 + Webpacker 4.0.2

My folders structure:

```
app
 |
 javascript
    |
    packs
      |
      application.js
      server_rendering.js
      components
       |
       main.js.jsx
       header.js.jsx
       body.js.jsx
       new_item.js.jsx
       all_items.js.jsx
```

In my application layout, I added `= javascript_pack_tag('application')`
In my index view, I have `= react_component('Main')`

But I have these errors:

[image: errors]
This is my application.js :

```
var componentRequireContext = require.context("components", true);
var ReactRailsUJS = require("react_ujs");
ReactRailsUJS.useContext(componentRequireContext);
```

main.js.jsx :

```
var Main = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Body />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

I tried to add `import React from ‘react’` in `main.js.jsx` but I still have the errors.

this is the first time I use React, I do not know where to look... Any help would be very appreciate

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try upgrading to https://github.com/shakacode/shakapacker